# .bashrc function isn't accepting commandline arguments

Tags: bash, function

I have a function that creates a .py file with bare minimum requirement for a Pyside script. The function creates the file with the text, but doesn't mark it as executable or open it in vim. Here is my code:

```
function newQt
{
        ~/Scripts/newQt.py "$@" #creates file with argument as name
        exify "$@" #alias for "chmod +x"
        vim "$@"
}
```

Comment: Aliases are expanded when a function definition is read, not when the function is executed.

Comment: FYI -- as an aside rather than an answer for the stated problem -- this syntax is gratuitously incompatible with POSIX. The compliant way to define a function is `newQt() {`, with no `function` keyword; even in things like `.bashrc` which will only be read by bash, it's still worth being in good habits and using bashisms only where they add value.

Comment: Are you executing `newQt` in an interactive shell? Aliases do not expand in non-interactive shells by default. Aliases are intended as typing aids in interactive shells; since you only need to type the command once here, when you define `newQt`, just type out the real command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exify is probably not doing anything because it is an alias which don't always expand.  Easiest just to make it a function too.

If this not the right answer, please add more details (invoke with "set -x" before the function for trace)